# how to export ssrs report data of multiple pages into one sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I have a ssrs report which display in multiple pages. I have set page size 10 and it's showing 10 recorod but I have to export all the data in one excel sheet because when i export it's comming multiple sheet. I need single sheet for all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Report Properties and then reduce the height  of your page. and remove your paging formula which you used in grouping. it will work.